# Call google Cloud function with service account permission

Tags: java, authentication, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I want to call the cloud function with authentication. The service account my-project-crendential has the role Cloud Functions-Invoker role.
So implemented the java code to call the cloud function with the name my-test-function

```
ServiceAccountCredentials
            .fromStream(new FileInputStream(PATH != null ? PATH : "my-project-crendential.json"))

this.settings = CloudFunctionsServiceSettings.newBuilder()
            .setCredentialsProvider(FixedCredentialsProvider.create(this.credentials))
            .build();


try (CloudFunctionsServiceClient client = CloudFunctionsServiceClient.create(this.settings)) {
      final var functionNameWithLocation = String.format(
          "projects/%s/locations/%s/functions/%s",
          "my-project-id",
          "europe-west4",
          "my-test-function"
      );
      CallFunctionRequest request = CallFunctionRequest.newBuilder()
             .setName(functionNameWithLocation)
             .setData(body.encode())
             .build();
      CallFunctionResponse response = client.callFunction(request);

      log.atDebug().log("Function response received {} ...", response.getResult());
            
 } catch (Exception e) {
      log.atError().withThrowable(e).log("Create repository failed ...");
 }
```

The function exists with url **https://europe-west4-my-project-id.cloudfunctions.net/my-test-function**

But the i always receive the exception:

> io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: PERMISSION_DENIED: Permission denied on 'locations/europe-west4' (or it may not exist)

so I don't think the permission is wrong, because the exception wrote the locations does not exists, but this is not true.
I use the dependency:

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
     <artifactId>google-cloud-functions</artifactId>
     <version>2.35.0</version>
</dependency>
```

How I can call the cloud function with the service account permission?

---

Trial 1.)
Depends of the feedback, the API is just for testing, so the service account doesn't have permission for that.
So I tried to get the oAuth Token like:

```
String serviceAccountKeyFile = path;//"/path/to/service-account-key.json";
    String projectId = "my-project-id";
    String location = "europe-west4";
    String functionName = "my-test-function";

    GoogleCredentials credentials = GoogleCredentials
            .fromStream(new FileInputStream(serviceAccountKeyFile))
            .createScoped("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform");

    String accessToken = credentials.refreshAccessToken().getTokenValue();
```

and then I call the get API:

```
String getApiUrl = String.format("https://cloudfunctions.googleapis.com/v2/projects/%s/locations/%s/functions/%s",
            projectId, location, functionName);
webClient.getAbs(getApiUrl)
            .bearerTokenAuthentication(identityToken)
            .putHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken)
            .send(getResponse -> {
                if (getResponse.succeeded()) {
```

// getResponse does not contains HTTPStrigger.URL attribute
}});

The response does not contains the https trigger url and when I call the cloud function via the url from the response I receive the same exception "location does not exists".

---

Trial 2.)
So I tried the example code: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/samples/functions-bearer-token?hl=de

```
        final var serviceAccountKeyFile = "/my/abs/path/to/my-project-secret-file.json";

    GoogleCredentials credentials = GoogleCredentials
            .fromStream(new FileInputStream(serviceAccountKeyFile))
            .createScoped("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform");

    final var audience = "https://europe-west4-my-project.cloudfunctions.net/my-function";

    if (!(credentials instanceof IdTokenProvider)) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Credentials are not an instance of IdTokenProvider.");
    }
    IdTokenCredentials tokenCredential =
            IdTokenCredentials.newBuilder()
                    .setIdTokenProvider((IdTokenProvider) credentials)
                    .setTargetAudience(audience)
                    .build();

    GenericUrl genericUrl = new GenericUrl("https://europe-west4-my-project.cloudfunctions.net/my-function");
    HttpCredentialsAdapter adapter = new HttpCredentialsAdapter(tokenCredential);
    HttpTransport transport = new NetHttpTransport();
    HttpRequest request = transport.createRequestFactory(adapter).buildGetRequest(genericUrl);
    final var result = request.execute();
    System.out.println(result.parseAsString());
```

The account has invoker role but now I receive the exception "Your client does not have permission to get URL `/my-function` from this server."
So different exception but still cannot call the cloud function. I don't have any idea anymore...

Comment: Are you performing tests with this code? Or will it be your production code (with potentially dozens of Cloud Functions call per second)?

Comment: It should be my production code. For testing I just can use the token (this work by the way).

Answer (score 1):

you sadly felt into a trap... You are right, there is a CALL API in the Cloud Functions library. However, you have to know that libraries are only wrappers to call API on Google Cloud.

The CALL API is this [one](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.locations.functions/call). As you can see, it's for testing only and not for regular calls.

---

If you want to use the Cloud Functions library, you must perform 2 things:

- Use the [GET API](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.locations.functions/get) (with Java Library use [this request](https://cloud.google.com/java/docs/reference/google-cloud-functions/latest/com.google.cloud.functions.v1.GetFunctionRequest)) to get the details and extract the [HTTPStrigger.URL attribute](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.locations.functions#HttpsTrigger)
- Generate an identity token with the OAuth2 library, add it in the authorization header (bearer token) of the request, and perform a HTTP call to the extracted URL

That's the correct way to use Cloud Functions.

Comment: Thank you I will try it and then I post the solution if it's working. By the way the why you need the additional steps to get the url? the url can be changed sometimes?

Comment: I just can call the v2 get api, than I receive the function data but without httpstrigger.URL the v1 just send me the same exception „location doesn’t exists“. So if I can the v2 api my oauth token should be correct but my cloud function still I cannot call :(